# JQuery mobile select menu not working properly

Tags: ruby, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, haml

I'm working on a Ruby and Sinatra project, and for a particular page I'm using jQuery mobile to create a mobile version of the page. I'm using knockout.js in the project as well.

I have a select box which appears correctly but when I make a selection, its text doesn't change though the value changes.

Here is my HAML code:

```
#subscriptions-content-div{'data-role' => 'content'}
  %ol{'data-role' => 'listview', 'data-inset' => 'true', 'data-bind' => 'foreach: misspelt'}
    %li
      %h3{ 'data-bind' => 'text: show_name'}
      - if shows.empty?
        No Shows in Database
      - else
        %select#show
          %option{'value' => 'no_choice', 'data-placeholder' => 'true'} Select a Show
          - shows.each do |show|
            %option{'value' => show.id}
              = show.name
      %button.btn{ 'data-bind' => 'click: $root.resolveSubscription', 'data-inline' => 'true', 'data-icon' => 'check', 'data-theme' => 'a'}
        Save
```

This is the HTML I get when I view the page source:

```
<div data-role='content' id='subscriptions-content-div'>
      <ol data-bind='foreach: misspelt' data-inset='true' data-role='listview'>

        <li>
          <h3 data-bind='text: show_name'></h3>
          <select id='show'>
            <option data-placeholder='true' value='no_choice'>Select a Show</option>
            <option value='50594de40ea69713630000de'>
              The Night Show
            </option>
            <option value='50594de40ea69713630000df'>
              Another Show
            </option>

            <option value='50594de40ea69713630000e0'>
              Yet Another Show
            </option>
          </select>
          <button class='btn' data-bind='click: $root.resolveSubscription' data-icon='check' data-inline='true' data-theme='a'>
            Save
          </button>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

The menu has 'Select a Show' as the title. When I select something else, this doesn't change but the value changes. I can tell it changes when I get the value of the selected option. Why won't the text change?

Comment: Does this fiddle reflect your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/aib42/kJJnJ/

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to defer the selects' initialization until after the KO bindings have been applied. I added `data-role="none"` attributes to the select elements and manually called `$.selectmenu()` after `ko.applyBindings()` - as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/aib42/xtz5B/

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding options to the select menu, then refreshing the select menu can be helpful.

```
$('#show').selectmenu();
$('#show').selectmenu('refresh');
```